# Count number of occurrence of "True" in last 5 rows of data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to count number of times value `True` appears in last `5` rows of my `pandas` dataframe column. There are `200` rows in total. I will be using this count (`emacount`) to validate and proceed (lets say `if count >=5`) do this..else..

The code I could come up with calculates the desired output for below. I used the same technique to get a similar count in 2 `if` statements as below (as that was the condition- checking for `True` in 2 columns and return the value if both columns had value `True`)

```
for now in range(len(df.index) - 15, len(df.index)):
            if df['in_side'][now]:
                if df['bb_side'][now]:
                    count = count + 1
                else:
                    count = count + 0
            else:
                count = count - 1
```

This seems to give number of `count` correctly.

I tried to apply the same logic for calculating `emacount` as below, but the output is not as desired (it fluctuates between `-4` and `4`) the output desired is for it to start from `0` , then depending on number of `True` in last `5` rows(rows `195` to `199`) of `in_trend` column , calculate `emacount` (varying from `0-5`) every time the dataframe is updated (running `scheduler`)

My code to calculate `emacount` and `count` is :

```
            count = 0
            emacount = 0

            for now in range(len(df.index) - 15, len(df.index)):
                if df['in_side'][now]:
                    if df['bb_side'][now]:
                        count = count + 1
                    else:
                        count = count + 0
                else:
                    count = count - 1

            for now2 in range(len(df.index) - 5, len(df.index)):
                if df['in_trend'][now2]:
                    emacount = emacount + 1
                else:
                    emacount = emacount -1
```

Below is my dataframe

```
    timestamp                     close    p_diff  ...  bb_side    emadiff  in_trend
180 2021-06-20 14:39:00+05:30  35205.83  0.348388  ...     True -17.065951     False
181 2021-06-20 14:42:00+05:30  35224.71  0.131215  ...     True -13.642527     False
182 2021-06-20 14:45:00+05:30  35189.40  0.044197  ...     True -15.706096     False
183 2021-06-20 14:48:00+05:30  35245.42  0.056861  ...     True  -8.875039     False
184 2021-06-20 14:51:00+05:30  35255.23  0.052819  ...     True  -7.095512     False
185 2021-06-20 14:54:00+05:30  35266.99  0.046941  ...     True  -5.299749     False
186 2021-06-20 14:57:00+05:30  35324.42  0.145489  ...     True   0.674513      True
187 2021-06-20 15:00:00+05:30  35370.05  0.124836  ...     True   4.955988      True
188 2021-06-20 15:03:00+05:30  35353.62  0.177176  ...     True   2.919227      True
189 2021-06-20 15:06:00+05:30  35333.78  0.104324  ...     True   0.751682      True
190 2021-06-20 15:09:00+05:30  35295.48  0.076508  ...     True  -2.967526     False
191 2021-06-20 15:12:00+05:30  35245.00  0.091845  ...     True  -7.492524     False
192 2021-06-20 15:15:00+05:30  35256.50  0.089293  ...     True  -5.683712     False
193 2021-06-20 15:18:00+05:30  35208.37  0.101059  ...     True  -9.726215     False
194 2021-06-20 15:21:00+05:30  34914.02  0.452258  ...     True -36.833243     False
195 2021-06-20 15:24:00+05:30  34987.38  0.589260  ...     True -26.338648     False
196 2021-06-20 15:27:00+05:30  34986.43  0.379041  ...     True -23.920682     False
197 2021-06-20 15:30:00+05:30  34944.72  0.245694  ...     True -25.614902     False
198 2021-06-20 15:33:00+05:30  34379.34  0.930663  ...    False -77.021102     False
199 2021-06-20 15:36:00+05:30  34489.50  0.962524  ...    False -59.194330     False
```

Thanks for stopping by. Have a safe and great day :)

EDIT 1 : the count of `emacount` is depending on `in_trend` column.

At current time `15:06` the emacount should have value 4 and going back at current time `15:03` value 3 and at `15:15` value should be 2

EDIT 2 : I am so sorry if my post was confusing. The value in `emacount` will be based in `in_trend` column. The values `True` or `False` in `in_trend` denote if the market is uptrend (True) or downtrend (False). So If I want to check for long term uptrend  then I will check last 5 values (thus >5 condition). If they are true then it is uptrend and even if any one of the row is False (count is <5 ) then the market is not in long term uptrend.

This function will repeat at interval of 3 min and so based on last 5 rows, we can determine if long term uptrend is going on or not

So based on the above data, there is no long term uptrend from 14:30 till 15:36 as the count never reaches 5 and there are no 5 True one after another

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker. Thanks for helping. Lets say time now is `15:06`(row 189 is last row 199) then `emacount` should have value `4` and going back at current time  `15:03` value `3` and at `15:15` value should be `2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just a single value for last five rows and all the columns:

```py
df.tail().apply(lambda x: sum(x==True)).sum()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
3
```

If you want to have separate values for each columns in last 5 rows:

```py
df.tail().apply(lambda x: sum(x==True))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
timestamp    0
close        0
p_diff       0
bb_side      3
emadiff      0
in_trend     0
dtype: int64
```

If you want to have separate counts for separated columns for last 5 rows:

```py
df.tail().apply(lambda x: sum(x==True), axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
195    1
196    1
197    1
198    0
199    0
dtype: int64
```

You get the last five rows by default with `tail()` but if you wanted a different number you could pass it as a parameter e.g. `tail(10)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `df.tail().apply(lambda x: sum(x==True))` seems to be valid as it return `3` because there are `3` True in latest last `5` rows of `bb_side` column. I want to count similar for only column `in_trend` and save it in `emacount`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a good starting point for you:

```py
df["long_term_trend"] = df["is_trend"].rolling(5).mean().eq(1)
df["ema_trend"] = df["is_trend"].ewm(span=5, adjust=False).mean()
```

`long_term_trend` addresses first problem you raised, while `ema_trend` is just ema of trend (1 being up, 0 being down).

I'm 80% sure that's your direction, however let me know, in case I misinterpreted your questions.